# Iterate over results in neo4j_client for C++

Tags: c++, libneo4j-client

I am looking for examples on usage for neo4j_client in C++.  In the [test suite](https://github.com/cleishm/libneo4j-client/blob/master/tests/check_result_stream.c) I see the neo4j_result_t, but no example of iterating or calling fields by name.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Results are returned as a [`neo4j_result_stream_t`](https://cleishm.github.io/libneo4j-client/doc/1.2/neo4j-client_8h.html#a0e726c5c4dfe02a5c621a9ab4b3d69a9), which represents a stream of result rows. The number of the columns in the result is available via [`neo4j_nfields`](https://cleishm.github.io/libneo4j-client/doc/1.2/neo4j-client_8h.html#a75840eac49113d9dd2acbab4586a5002), and their names via [`neo4j_fieldname`](https://cleishm.github.io/libneo4j-client/doc/1.2/neo4j-client_8h.html#a0e49dd65d4e3f49498c3eaaf4c86af49), both of which take the [`neo4j_result_stream_t`](https://cleishm.github.io/libneo4j-client/doc/1.2/neo4j-client_8h.html#a0e726c5c4dfe02a5c621a9ab4b3d69a9) pointer as a parameter.

To iterate over the result rows, use [`neo4j_fetch_next`](https://cleishm.github.io/libneo4j-client/doc/1.2/neo4j-client_8h.html#a25186e637ef83e7bd77cc089be1822c8) which returns a [`neo4j_result_t`](https://cleishm.github.io/libneo4j-client/doc/1.2/neo4j-client_8h.html#a684fa02daeb236ea6d4d7671a251fe05). And to extract values for each column from the row (the fields), pass the pointer to [`neo4j_result_field`](https://cleishm.github.io/libneo4j-client/doc/1.2/neo4j-client_8h.html#abd8ce4a012c694dcad787d62ec335dac) (along with the index of the column).

An example would be something like this:

```
neo4j_result_stream_t *results =
        neo4j_run(session, "MATCH (n) RETURN n.name, n.age", neo4j_null);
if (results == NULL)
{
    neo4j_perror(stderr, errno, "Failed to run statement");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

int ncolumns = neo4j_nfields(results);
if (ncolumns < 0)
{
    neo4j_perror(stderr, errno, "Failed to retrieve results");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
neo4j_result_t *result;
while ((result = neo4j_fetch_next(results)) != NULL)
{
    unsigned int i;
    for (i = 0; i < ncolumns; ++i)
    {
        if (i > 0)
        {
            printf(", ");
        }
        neo4j_value_t value = neo4j_result_field(result, i);
        neo4j_fprint(value, stdout);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, and a follow up:  can you call a field by name?  like `neo4j_result_field(result, "age")`?  Less intelligently: how do I get the age to come back as an `int`?  I saw your `string` example.

Comment: Unfortunately not. The [Bolt Protocol](http://boltprotocol.org) offers no guarantee that a each column in the result has a unique name, so such a call could return an ambiguous result.

Comment: That said, I checked and Neo4j will refuse to run a Cypher command that would return duplicated column names. So you're unlikely to encounter this in practice and you could probably create a wrapper function fairly safely.